# How to focusout good with an autocomplete click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have an input text and when it loses focus (focusout) the script POST (updates the text in the server) BUT, when I click in the autocomplete options, the sent text is different, look:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
   var values = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "...", "value4"];
   $('input').bind( 'focusout', function() {
      $.post( '/add_value', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {} );
   });
   $('input').autocomplete({source:values} );
});
</script>
<form>
   <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

The user writes in the input: "va", then the autocomplete show something like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

When the user click the autocomplete BOX the input loses focus, and send the value "va" to the server and not the clicked value.

The question is: How to control the click event to send the clicked value in the autocomplete and not the writer.

Comment: Check the `select` event in http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
var send_now = true;

$('input').bind( 'focusout', function() {
   if (send_now) {
          $.post( '/add_value', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {} );
      }
   });

$('.attribute_name').autocomplete( { source: values} );  

$('form').delegate( 'input', 'autocompleteopen', function() {                        
    send_now = false;
});

$('form').delegate( 'input', 'autocompleteclose', function() {
    $(this).focus();
    send_now = true;                    
});
```